# png file shows up on simulator, but not ipad

Tags: ios, image, uiimage, png

I'm struggling with a problem that maybe someone can help me with.
    [slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle_black.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

The above code correctly displays the image in the ipad simulator, but not on the actual ipad device.  I have had a look at other threads and have tried the following with no success:
- lowercase letters (filenames are as shown, no capitals)
- re-created the file in case it was corrupt
- clean rebuild
- seems to be in the bundle (build phases->copy bundle resources has this file listed)

my ipad is an ipad1, ios 5.

Any other suggestions I could try?

Comment: Alright figured this out.  Apparently, there wasn't anything wrong with the image or how I was doing it.  It seems in iOS5, doing slider.enabled = NO; breaks the [slider setThumbImage:] call.  iOS6 is fine.  Changing this to slider.userInteractionEnabled = NO fixes this on both iOS5 and iOS6

Answer (score 1):

@Jason,

Image name is Case-sensitive in IPhone/Ipad, whereas in simulator image name is not case-sensitive. Check it once.

Comment: This answer explained the problem when I had it. The image file was named "neck highlight.jpg." In my code, "neckHighlight" worked in the simulator but not the iPad(3). When I changed the code to match the filename capitalization it worked.

Answer (score 0):

May be the image is not properly added in the bundle.

things to do.

- Check if multiple images exist in same name.If there remove unwanted
- Remove the image from project and the folder.Add to the resource folder again .add to project and run again.
- Last but not least .Duplicate the image Give it another name ,Add to folder and project and run it

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have deleted image from the App, on simulator it can take reference of deleted images but not on device.